# Problema com WSDL da SIGEP

Tags: php, web-service, aplicação-web, wsdl

Estou a um tempo com um projeto dos correios, tive que fazer uma conexão com o webservice SIGEP WEB, encontrei algo já em desenvolvimento em, estava usando o mesmo e tudo OK, de um dia para o outro o mesmo parou de funcionar, fiz alguns testes e reparei que o webservice de teste consigo utilizar normalmente, porem o de produção da um erro de timeout.

Tenho usuários validos porem mesmo assim não funciona, criei um script simples:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL|E_STRICT');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$client = new SoapClient("https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl");

$function = 'buscaCliente';

$arguments= array('ConvertTemp' => array(
                        'idContrato' => "0000000000",
                        'idCartaoPostagem' => "0000000000",
                        'usuario'   => "usuario",
                        'senha'      => "senha"
                ));
$options = array('location' => "https://apps.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente");
 echo "aqui";
$result = $client->__Call($function, $arguments, $options);

echo 'Response: ';

foreach($result as $row){
    foreach((object)$row->contratos->cartoesPostagem->servicos as $row2){
        echo $row2->codigo;
        echo "
";
    }
}
```

o Mesmo funciona no PHP 5.2 porem não funciona no PHP 5.3, ocorre o mesmo erro de tempo limite.

O sistema está desenvolvido em 5.3 e preciso manter isso.

Alguém tem algum motivo para isso ocorrer?

Comment: projeto que peguei e usei no sistema: (http://stavarengo.github.io/php-sigep/)

Comment: [Tente aumentar o timeout](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: o timeout é suficiente pois o mesmo funcionava anteriormente normalmente.

Comment: Olá, descobriu alguma solução para o timeout?

Comment: Notei aqui no nosso projeto que o endereço de produção só funciona no nosso servidor (que possui https). Pode ser isso, já que a API do cartão de crédito também só funciona a partir dali. De qualquer forma, se tiver alguma resposta certa, já ajuda.

Comment: O problema ocorre na versão do PHP, O problema é que o sistema não consegue se conectar com o webservice usando o link direto, pra resolver eu baixei o código do webservice e salvei em formato wsdl, ai em vez de passar o link eu passo o caminho para o arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

O index do array `$arguments` não pode ser "ConvertTemp", ele precisa ser "buscaCliente".

```
$arguments= array('buscaCliente' => array(
                    'idContrato' => "0000000000",
                    'idCartaoPostagem' => "0000000000",
                    'usuario'   => "usuario",
                    'senha'      => "senha"
            ));
```